# How to focus on Unity and Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I use WebCamTexture to show a camera view.

The code is like below.

`var w = new WebCamTexture(devices[0].name);
    this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture=w;
    w.Play ();`

I think the quality of web camera is, however, worse than other Android camera application.

Can I use auto-focus option of android? Or can I trigger focus manually?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use auto-focus option of android? Or can I trigger focus
>   manually?

**No**.

You can use the [NatCam plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/52154). It is expensive but worth it in the long run as it supports every platform.

Another option is to build a Java plugin that replaces the `WebCamTexture`. This is not an easy task but you can start with this [open source one](https://github.com/mopsicus/native-android-camera-unity) and easily add a focus function to it. Note that this will only work on Android.